# Intel compiler options for optimizating opencl

Tags: opencl, intel, compiler-optimization

I wrote a simple Matrix multiplication code in openCl on Intel HD graphics (Windows 7, MS VS 2010). Now I want to optimize it using compiler options.

What compiler options are available for Intel implementation?  Please point me to a useful link.

I would also like to know how to set these compiler options ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set options to OpenCL compiler with options parameter of the clBuildProgram.

```
char options[] = "-cl-unsafe-math-optimizations -cl-mad-enable";
clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, options, NULL, NULL);
```

Available options are listed in Khronos clBuildProgram documentation:
http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html

Comment: do you know if Intel has any additional build optional available?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any.

Comment: I am a newbie on OpenCL. Could you let me know where do we do these option ? say if I compile my opencl like `gcc (_OR_) clang -O3 -I<INCLUDES> APP.c -framework OpenCL -lm`, that line you mentioned should be included in the .c file you mean? or pass it as command-line option. Thanks :)

Comment: In the .c code file you have call for function 'clBuildProgram'. It takes char array as fourth argument. You can set your own option string to it like shown above.